# Recent activity reputation statistics are incorrect on page load

Tags: bug, status-completed, recent-activity

I think there was an old UserVoice issue on this, but I'm still seeing some weird behavior.  I've gotten used to it, but it is still annoying.

If you click on the Recent Activity link, the summary shown is not always correct.  Sometimes it is missing some activity. You can see this if you click on the Today link.  As often as not, for me anyway, more reputation shows up in the calculation even though the time range displayed at the top of the page does not change (except for the current time).

Comment: This is pretty annoying indeed. It shows *"Showing 2009-08-25 to 2009-08-25 ; current time is 2009-08-25 22:52:12 UTC"* by default and after clicking on **Today**, but the **Today** version is showing a lot more.

Answer (score 5):

I believe the summary shown is "today since *server* midnight." When you click on "Today" it will display "today since *UTC* midnight."

In other words, I believe it misses the first 7 or 8 hours of the day (I think the servers are on PST/PDT).

And yes, I think that's a bug.

Comment: Beat me to it, Jon.

Comment: That is actually the most concise and clear explanation of it I have seen so far.

Comment: For me it happens at 6pm.

Comment: @Brad: What do you mean by "happens at 6pm"? @TheTXI: That's probably what I get for having to describe time zone issues to users and colleagues :)